# htaccess file not rewriting properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a problem in my .htaccess using Rewrite Rule.
Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/user/$ user.php?u=$1
```

The error is in  the bottom two lines, where anybody going to /user/foo
would see the result of going to /user?u=foo.

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to achieve and how it fails? Can you give us an example where your rule fails, telling us what you would expect and what you have instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/?$ user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?user/([\w-]+)/?$ user.php?u=$1 [L]
```